# Is there a max number of CosmosClient instances allowed per a process?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is there any limitation in a number of CosmosClient objects that can be created in a process? Obviously we don't want to create redundant objects, but we would like to know if there is the upper limit.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain why you would have many clients? Is each connecting to a different Cosmos account?

Comment: our service has multiple components accessing databases in the same cosmos account. each of those components needs CosmosClient. we have an internal logic to share DocumentClient (we are in the middle of updating our code to use cosmos sdk 3.0) among those components because i believe, we were told that there is a limit in a number of DocumentClient objects that we can create per process. we would like to know if there is such limit for CosmosClient. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no technical limit to the number of CosmosClients.

Each CosmosClient instance maintains it's own pool of connections, so having many might lead to Connection limiting or SNAT port exhaustion on some environments. Some environments have a limit on the number of connections that can be opened.

The [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql#sdk-usage) is to have a Singleton CosmosClient per account for the lifetime of your application. Based on your comments, if you have many components accessing different databases, but within the same account, you should maintain a Singleton instance and just inject it or share it across components.